# Is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \cosh^2 x & \cosh^2 x\\ -\sinh^2x&-\sinh^2x\end{pmatrix}$ significant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \cosh^2 x & \cosh^2 x\\ -\sinh^2x&-\sinh^2x\end{pmatrix}$ significant?

The reason I am asking is as follows. As a 'challenge' question at the end of my textbook it asked  to prove by induction that if
$$\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix} \cosh^2 x & \cosh^2 x\\ -\sinh^2x&-\sinh^2x\end{pmatrix}$$
then for $n\in\mathbb N$
$$\textbf{A}^n=\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix} \cosh^2 x & \cosh^2 x\\ -\sinh^2x&-\sinh^2x\end{pmatrix}$$
I proved this easily, but it struck me that this matrix behaves in exactly the same way as the identity matrices. Of course, this result is equivalent to
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos^2 x & \cos^2 x\\ \sin^2x&\sin^2x\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix} \cos^2 x & \cos^2 x\\ \sin^2x&\sin^2x\end{pmatrix}$$
So, are  these results used in  more advanced linear algebra or university level maths? It just seems too coincidental not to be used in some more advanced results or topics.

Comment: This is simply one of the many [idempotent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix).

Comment: No – what you have in both cases is a rank one matrix (ie all columns are colinear – in other words, it is a product $BC$ with $B$ being $2 \times 1$ and $C$ being $1 \times 2$) with trace (sum of diagonal coefficients) $1$. All such matrices $A$ satisfy $A^2=A$ (thus $A^n=A$ for each $n$).

Comment: @Mindlack that's very interesting, thank you.

Comment: In fact, both of these matrix families satisfy not only $a^2=a$, but $ab=a$, i.e. all of their elements are right-identities (so of course, none are left-identities).

Comment: @J.G. what are right/left -identities?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element#Definitions). If $lx=x$ for all $x$, $l$ is a left-identity; if $xr=x$ for all $x$, $r$ is a right-identity. If both exist, $l=lr=r$, so there's one of each, and it's the same two-sided identity; and therefore, if multiple exist of one one-sided type, none exist of the other.